# Scraping from an ambiguous tag using Beautifulsoup

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the college that an individual attended. In this particular code below, which I got after running soup.find_all() to return all the tags, the college is Auburn. I know that tags mark the component types in HTML documents. So in this case, would the relevant tag I am looking for be the

```
<a href='../College..."?
```

If so, how would I return the college name using BeautifulSoup?

```
<img height="75" id="CollegeLogo" 
id="CollegeCommit" style="color: white; font-size: 22px; 
text-decoration: underline dotted">Auburn</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the id

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<img height="75" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_img4yearCollegeLogo" 
onerror="this.style.display='none'" src="https://5409b91eba8a3c695263- 
e57580eaf7522c9542febdac7b28f14a.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/1566.png"/>
</p><div class="Five"></div>
<a href="../College/CollegeCommitments.aspx?Grad=2012&amp;college=1566" 
id="ContentPlaceHolder1_hl4yearCommit" style="color: white; font-size: 22px; 
text-decoration: underline dotted">Auburn</a>
</div>
'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
href = soup.select_one('#ContentPlaceHolder1_hl4yearCommit')['href']
```

Less efficient but you could substring match on an attribute with [* contains, ^ starts with, or $ ends with operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) e.g.

```
href = soup.select_one('[id$=yearCommit]')['href']
```